# Remove the comma from Ghost Handlebars Template？

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, ghost

When traverse the tags, suddenly have comma. This may not be willing to see the effect. I am try remove the comma, but is there any way to remove `,`? I saw the [Ghost blog Document](http://themes.ghost.org/docs/tags) when not quite sure how to remove comma.

#### Look at the picture：

[image]

#### post.hbs:

```
<span class="post-meta">
      {{#if tags}} 
          {{tags}} 
      {{/if}}
</span>
```

Comment: Your not traversing the `tags` here, your checking for the existences and then outputting that..   But your check is not really needed anyway.. try ->  `{{#tags}}{{.}}{{/tags}}`

Comment: @Keith Please do not post answers as comments.  Doing so subverts StackOverflow's quality controls for answers, _and_ deprives you of those sweet sweet answer points.

Comment: @Keith I tried, but I couldn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what problems you was having.

But I've knocked up quick snippet that shows it working.

```js
var source = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML; 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
  tags: ["Spring Boot", "MyBatis", "CRUD"]
};


document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = template(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <span class="post-meta">
    {{#tags}}
    {{.}}&nbsp;
    {{/tags}}
  </span>
</script>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to use a workaround to achieve this, there's a `separator` attribute of the `{{tags}}` helper specifically designed for customising this.

Comment: Looping over tags manually & then hardcoding a space is working around the natural behaviour of the `{{tags}}` helper that was created for the sole purpose of doing this for you. The comma separator is a customisable default.

Comment: The Op posted `Remove the comma from Handlebars Template`  although he does mention ghost, I responded based on Handlebars, and this does not have the #tags helper function.

Comment: Sure, but if this was pure handlebars, there wouldn't be a comma there to begin with - it's being added by the `{{tags}}` helper that is being used - the documentation for which the OP included in their question.

Comment: FYI I've been trialling out the idea of us (Ghost) switching our standard community support from using slack to stackoverflow. The community here seems to be very hostile and helping people here is a horrible experience.

Comment: @ErisDS  I think your miss-reading my responses,.. I don't know anything about Ghost, I've only replied to this questions based on the Javascript & Handlebars.  For me #tags means nothing special.  This is more of a problem with SO sometimes, the tags can give out a much broader response than wanted / required.  As such, my response is most likely miss-leading and I will delete it..

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean. To me the question was obviously specific to Ghost - from the code, the link & the screenshot. However the title doesn't actually explicitly state this. I've made a suggestion to include the word Ghost in the title, maybe my edit will get accepted and that will clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In Ghost `{{tags}}` is a special helper that outputs a list of tags with full HTML.

The documentation page that you linked to: https://themes.ghost.org/docs/tags contains full details of how the output can be modified with various attributes passed to the helper.

In your case, you need to change the value of `separator` from the default of `,` (comma and space) to (presumably) just a space:

`{{tags separator=" "}}`